# Losing ERC20 token without trace on etherscan

Tags: ether, metamask, etherscan

I would like to know if there is a way to take a token from an account without letting a trace on etherscan ?

I recently swapped some ETHs for a Base Protocol token and i got around 2940 BASE in the end, but when i tried to swap them again after a few hours, i only found 2307 on my balance.

Here is a screenshot of the token transactions
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of BASE protocol. Rebase happens in specific times every day and that can be negative rebase or positive rebase. If price is higher than 0.575$, then positive effect happens and you will % of your tokens. But they will keep total amount in USD. That's how BASE work.